# while fetching repeated numbers in array i am getting error

Tags: java

```
package interview;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class multiple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[] =  { 2, 4 ,1, 6,4, 5 , 40 , -1};
    //int i =arr.length;
    //System.out.println(i);

    for(int i=0; i<(arr.length) ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<(arr.length) ; j++)

        {
            if(arr[i] ==arr[j])
            {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);

        }

        }

    }
```

output :

```
4
4
1
6
4
4
5
40
-1
```

I am getting wrong output for the code as i want to fetch the repeated occuring numbers in array.

Comment: Side note: There's no purpose served by the `()` in `i<(arr.length)`/`j<(arr.length)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should start your inner loop from `i + 1` to the following:

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
```

Otherwise, you start comparing objects you already compared in previous iterations

Please note that this is a suboptimal approach for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You can also use a `Set<Integer>`

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera: The post writes about `interview` so I thought just to answer what was asked instead of giving the optimal approach.

Comment: I also think that your approach is the most appropriate (+1). However, I think adding the use of collections can help OP to know them better.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you are keeping the value of `j` as constant always at the index 1 and `i` is changing so for the first few iterations the comparisons will be proper.

But once `i` is greater than `j` we are going to see extras in the output as they have been already compared and considered. So `j` needs to be one more than the value of `i` (dynamic) so that no extra comparisons are made.

Just to reduce the o(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity we can use the below approach:

```
Set<Integer> uniqueSet = new HashSet<>();
for(int i =0; i< arr.length; i++){
     if(!uniqueSet.add(arr[i])){
         System.out.println(arr[i]);
     }
}
```

We are adding the number to a `HashSet`, if the number is not present the `add` method will return `true` and if() condition *would not be satisfied* but if the number is already added in the `HashSet` the `add` would return `false` and consequently the if() is satisfied and number is detected as a duplicate.